# How to save images from Google Earth Engine using Python?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I would like to export images from image collection using Python. This is what I am doing:

```
cover = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A2').filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-05-01'))\
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
```

Then I clipped the image over a geometry of interest from a shapefile

```
import geopandas as gdp
myShp = gdp.read_file(myGdp)
def returnCityBoundary(gdf):
  bounds = gdf.total_bounds
  lon_point_list = [bounds[0], bounds[0], bounds[2], bounds[2]]
  lat_point_list = [bounds[1], bounds[3], bounds[3], bounds[1]]
  polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
  crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
  polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom]) 
  geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[bounds[0], bounds[1]],
            [bounds[0], bounds[3]],
            [bounds[2], bounds[3]],
            [bounds[2], bounds[1]]]])
  return geometry

  geometry = returnCityBoundary(gdf)
```

In this way I can clip the images over the region of interest.

```
cover_clipped = cover.map(lambda image : image.clip(geometry)) ## get images only for the region (clip to geometry)
```

I can also show the images as described [here](https://github.com/csaybar/EEwPython/blob/master/1_Introduction.ipynb). This an example from Paris:

[image]

How should I do to save ImageCollection as images? I am trying to do the following but it only opens the drive folder without saving anything inside.

```
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**{
    'image': cover_clipped,
    'description': 'imageToDriveExample',
    'folder':'Example_folder',
    'scale': 100
})
task.start()
```